# Fetch update in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, core-data, fetch, nsfetchrequest

this is the code in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
-(IBAction)fetch:(id)sender{
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Foo" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == 'some title'"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (fetchedObjects == nil) {NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);}
NSMutableArray *fooArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (Foo *f in fetchedObjects) {
    //here another fastenum for a to-many relationship
    for(Bar *b in f.relationship){
        [fooArray addObject:b.title];
    }
}
```

Everytime I perform the fetch action, even if I've changed the app.storedata file via UI and checked the changes in finder, the result is always the same until i quit the application. After a restart, the fetch result is up to date and aligned with the app.storedata file. The fooArray count is always the same, regardless if I add some entries in the entities and coredata save everything.
I've tried with [fetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:YES] but it doesn't affect the behaviour.
How to update the fetch result while the app is running?

UPDATE: i've "solved" the problem with this workaround:

```
-(IBACTION)fetch:(id)sender{
    _managedObjectContext = nil;
    _persistenStoreCoordinator = nil;
    //rest of the code...
```

Is this workaround a final solution? Is there a more "correct" way to solve this problem?

Comment: are you saving context ?

Comment: Yes, as I've mentioned above, the app is performing the right save action and the app.storedata file is updated while the app is running.